# SumIF by month and only for the weekends

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

So I came to the issue I can't solve by myself. I made an arrayformula which counts the days only in the given month in a range which works perfectly but I couldn't figure out how to make that formula to count in a separate column only the weekend works.

My formula which counts the days in the specified month is :

`=ArrayFormula(sumif(month($C$32:$AK$32),$AL$33, C34:AK34))`
[image: How the spreadsheet part looks like]

I did try to use to combine the weekdays with my original formula:

`=ArrayFormula(sumifS(month($C$32:$AK$32),$AL$33,C34:AK34,$C$32:$AK$32,WEEKDAY(C32:AK32,2)>5))`

Comment: slight amend to your current formula: `=arrayformula(sumifs( C34:AK34, month($C$32:$AK$32),$AL$33, WEEKDAY($C$32:$AK$32,2),">5"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($C$32:$AK$32)=$AL$33)*(WEEKDAY($C$32:$AK$32, 2)>5)*C34:AK34))`

Comment: Tested and works perfectly the, previously I thought it's not working as it should but it does. Thanks
Sumproduct and sumifs can replace each other as I see if they are used correctly.